# How to choose a GeoJSON file and load it into OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, vector-layer

I have a code in OpenLayers, which from a layer, it is possible to save the data in a GeoJSON file.
Follow the code.

```
function downloadGeoJSON(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();      
}

var json = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures(), {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
downloadGeoJSON(json, 'my_layer.geojson', 'text/plain');
```

Now, I need to do the reverse: read the name of a file, for example:

> file_upload: 'c:/my_layer.geojon'

and upload this layer to my vector_layer layer. Can someone help me?

```
var vector_source = new ol.source.Vector();
        
var vector_layer = new ol.layer.Vector( { 
    title: 'My Layer',
    source: vector_source, 
    style: function (f) {
        return [
            style_draw, 
            new ol.style.Style({
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                    text: f.get('NOME'),
                    font: 'bold 20px Calibri,sans-serif', //'bold 14px sans-serif',
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ width: 2.5, color: [255,255,255] }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({  color: $("#color_text").val() }),
                })
            }),
        ]
    }
});
```

[EDIT] file contents: c:/my_layer.geojon

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features":[
 {"type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Point","coordinates": 
            [-46.443328857421875,-23.689018558178915]
       }, 
       "properties":{"ID":1,"NOME":"Ponto 1"}
 },
 {"type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Point","coordinates": 
            [-46.45500183105469,-23.66921021892003]
       },
       "properties":{"ID":2,"NOME":"Ponto 2"}
  }
```

]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could drag and drop the file as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html

Otherwise add a file input element to your HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="input-file">
```

and some JavaScript to handle it:

```
document.getElementById('input-file').addEventListener('change', function () {
  var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]),
  });
  source.on('featuresloadend', function () {
    map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
  });
  vector_layer.setSource(source);
});
```

or if you already have a source

```
document.getElementById('input-file').addEventListener('change', function () {
  this.files[0].text().then(function(text){
    vector_source.addFeatures(
      new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(text, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})
    )
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to run your code and it shows the geojson data, but it doesn't update 'on the fly'. The update only occurs when I click on another button, for example to draw a line. I'm using Openlayers v5.

Comment: There is no `featuresloadend` event in V5.  Try using `source.once('changed', ` instead.

Comment: Mike, is it possible to add the fetaures with the following code, from a file? `vector_source.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject,
{dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
        );`
geojsonObject here I created the data in code. How to change to fetch data the this.files[0]?

Comment: Yes, added to the answer

Comment: thank you very much. I got it with your code, that's exactly what I needed. It's still not auto-updating though, but since I have multiple iterations buttons to draw, it might be something in my code. I'll take it easy. Thanks